# feign.RetryableException: Connection reset executing POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign, broken-pipe

I'm calling a url from an external server and in 5% of cases I get this problem.
i get java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe,
my doubt is if the problem is in my application or the external service that for some reason is canceling the request

i`m using kotlin + spring boot + feign client

```
feign.RetryableException: Connection reset executing POST https://xpto.com/test // real url omitted
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:249)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:129)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy228.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.creditas.b2bapi.infrastructure.adapter.BcrediAdapter.createLead(BcrediAdapter.kt:22)
    at com.creditas.b2bapi.service.LeadBcrediService.createBcrediLead(LeadBcrediService.kt:44)
    at com.creditas.b2bapi.service.LeadBcrediService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7c46a37.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    ... 142 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:441)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:825)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1007)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:82)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:355)
        ... 166 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:324)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:802)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:937)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1409)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1022)
    ... 162 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried making the request to external server using any rest client or simply by using curl command? If you face the same issue, then it doesn't look to be the issue of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this type of error, my solution was to change the jdk I was using and the exception disappeared! So I don't really know the root of the problem, but changing jdk works for me. You can try using the JDKs provided by intellij. This article can be of great help. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk